# PyQGIS setting scalebar to kilometers

Tags: pyqgis, layouts, scale-bar

I have a pyqgis script that exports multiple maps.

I am using a specific layout and map item.
The scalebar should be variable depending on the location.

I have the following scalebar code snippet:

```
        scalebar_item = layout.itemById("Scalebar")
        scalebar_item.setLinkedMap(map_item)
        scalebar_item.applyDefaultSize()
```

First line searches for scalebar item in the layout by id.

Second line links the scalebar to the map_item variable.

And 3rd line applying the default size helps me to keep the scalebar within the map item. There might be cases of low scale maps where my scalebar gets out of the map item itself.

**Issue:**
The 3rd line resets my measuring units from Kilometers to meters.

I have tried to use "**scalebar_item.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.DistanceKilometers)**" as a 4th line but it does not work and the scale remains in meters.

I have also tried to store the units before **applyDefaultSize()** with **current_units = scalebar_item.units()**

Then apply this as a last line:
**scalebar_item.setUnits(current_units)**

Both do not work. What am I missing out?